# new pandas dataframe row based on existing data frame?

Tags: python, pandas

Is it possible to create a row based on values of a previous row?

Lets say

```
    Name     Location     Amount
1   xyz      london        23423
```

is a row in a DF. and I want to scan the DF, and if amount > 2000 and Location == london I want to append another row that keeps the location and amount of row 1 but changes name to EEE

As per my note, I would like the output to be the same DF but this:

```
    Name     Location     Amount
1   xyz      london        23423
2   EEE      london        23424
```

Answer (score 0):

You can slice the dataframe based on the conditions, then change the name.

```
df2 = df[df.Location.eq('london') & df.Amount.gt(2000)].reset_index(drop=True)
df2.Name = 'EEE'
```

Comment: but that would create a new df right?
I would like it to create a new row in the existing df:
 Name     Location     Amount
1   xyz      london        23423
2  EEE     london        23423

Comment: I guess its possible to do it this way, have a second DF, and then have the two DFs concat to each other? but i am hoping there is a cleaner way to do this